# Python - numpy arrays - Abelian sandpile

Tags: python, numpy, cellular-automata

I'm trying to do the Abelian sandpile model using a simple numpy array.
When a 'pile' is 4 >=, then it collapse among its neighbors.
I understand how the "gravity" thing works, but I can't think of a way of making it.
Here's the code to make my array :

```py
import numpy as np
spile = np.zeros((5, 5), dtype=np.uint32)
spile[2, 2] = 16
```

Which gives me the following :

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 16,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=uint32)
```

Now, I need the "gravity" code that does these steps of calculation :

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  4,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  4,  0,  4,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  4,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=uint32)


array([[ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  2,  1,  2,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  0,  1,  1],
       [ 0,  2,  1,  2,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0]], dtype=uint32)
```

The last array is the final result I'm trying to get.
I'm not trying to make you guys code for me, I just need some ideas as I've never ever did such a thing (but feel free to provide a code if you're that kind :p ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.divmod` to identify where the cells tumble and how much tumbles.  Then use array slicing to shift the amounts tumbled and add back into the sandpile.

```
import numpy as np      
spile = np.zeros((5, 5), dtype=np.uint32)
spile[2, 2] = 16         

def do_add( spile, tumbled ):
    """ Updates spile in place """
    spile[ :-1, :] += tumbled[ 1:, :] # Shift N and add                 
    spile[ 1:, :] += tumbled[ :-1, :] # Shift S   
    spile[ :, :-1] += tumbled[ :, 1:] # Shift W
    spile[ :, 1:] += tumbled[ :, :-1] # Shift E

def tumble( spile ):
    while ( spile > 3 ).any():
        tumbled, spile = np.divmod( spile, 4 )
        do_add( spile, tumbled )
        # print( spile, '\n' )  # Uncomment to print steps
    return spile

print( tumble( spile ) ) 
# or tumble( spile ); print( spile )

# [[0 0 1 0 0]
# [0 2 1 2 0]
# [1 1 0 1 1]
# [0 2 1 2 0]
# [0 0 1 0 0]]
```

Uncommented print statement prints these results

```
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 4 0 0]
 [0 4 0 4 0]
 [0 0 4 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]] 

[[0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 2 0 2 0]
 [1 0 4 0 1]
 [0 2 0 2 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]] 

[[0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 2 1 2 0]
 [1 1 0 1 1]
 [0 2 1 2 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]]
```

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Abelian_sandpile_model

Comment: Thank you so much! Learnt a lot from it
How would you do to print only the last result tho ?

Comment: Put the print statement outside the while loop.  I put it inside to see what was happening.  I've changed the answer.  Delete whichever print ststement you don't need.  You could put the while loop in a function to run with any spile and return a result.

Comment: Nice! Is it possible to have a function that does the work only by calling the spile var ? Like do_the_work(spile) and then I'll only have to print(spile) to get the last one ?

Comment: Transformed the while loop to a function.  Have you looked at rosettacode? link in the answer.

Comment: Did not know about this site, thank you so much for your work!